# Convert list of numbers into a string in Python containing the actual values

Tags: python, list

This is in python. I'm new to python, but not to programming.

`x = [2, 0, 0 , 0x40, 0x25, 6, 3]`

I want to turn it into a string of the format

`x2 = "\0x02\0x00\0x00\0x40\0x25\0x06\0x03"`

The binary values from the list are in the string. I can do it with brute force, but there has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: What does your "brute force" method look like?

Comment: Why do you want all the `\0`s in the string? `struct.pack` is probably what you want.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
x = [2, 0, 0 , 0x40, 0x25, 6, 3]
x2 = ''

for num in x:
    x2 += '\\0x{:02x}'.format(num)

>>> print(x2)
\0x02\0x00\0x00\0x40\0x25\0x06\0x03
```

Comment: You attempt is good but may require minor change. Output contains \0x2 as opposed to \0x02. I have no idea if they both are equivalent or not

Comment: Your string has a backslash character followed by a zero character, but the OP's example has a string with literal null characters in it.

Comment: I edited my answer to account for the formatting. The answer should be complete now. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: `'\\' + "0x{:02x}".format(num)` == `"\\0x{:02x}".format(num)` and in Python 3.6+ `f"\\0x{num:02x}"`

Comment: Thanks guys. I think we are getting close. The output string would contain only two printable characters. The 0x40 maps to a "@" and the 0x25 maps to a "%". I want the nulls, ascii etx ans stx, etc. in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple enough...

```
>>> print(''.join(r'\0x'+'%02x'%i for i in x))
\0x02\0x00\0x00\0x40\0x25\0x06\0x03
```

Note the use of "print" - if you report the string itself, it apparently doubles up the "\" on displaying it:

```
>>> ''.join(r'\0x'+'%02x'%i for i in x)
'\\0x02\\0x00\\0x00\\0x40\\0x25\\0x06\\0x03'
```

however, the look at the characters themselves, you will see that this is a shell/display issue:

```
>>> x2 = ''.join(r'\0x'+'%02x'%i for i in x)
>>> print x2[0], x2[1], x2[2], x2[3], x2[4], x2[5]
\ 0 x 0 2 \
```

Comment: There should only be two printable characters in the string, a "@" which maps to the "0x40" and a "%" which maps to 0x25. I want the nulls and other unprintable characters in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one problem... I should have had "\x02\x00\x00\x40" and so on  instead of "\0x02\0x00\0x00\0x40" and so on. The problem was the "**0**x". So the wrong thing was in the string in the first place.

The brute force method is:
x2 = ""
for i in x
   x2 = x2 + chr(i)

x2 now is a string with the correct values. There should be a better way.